# I bought a house and the ceiling fan light in one of the bedrooms has three lights 2 regular and then one is candelabra. Is this safe and why?

Tags: electrical

Ceiling fan light has 2 regular light fixtures and one candelabra fixture. Is this normal and safe?

Comment: what does this mean? ... `2 regular light fixtures and one candelabra fixture`

Comment: Is one a nite light.

Comment: Are you talking about the light *bulbs*, or the actual lamp *sockets* in the ceiling fan?

Comment: 2 regular fitures in the fan itself and then one candelabra fixture in the fan also 3 total mix and match no nightlight

Comment: Can you get us photos of the situation please?

Answer (score 4):

All those types of lightbulb socket are safe for normal voltage lightbulbs, so no need to be concerned about the safety of it on that basis. *If there are any signs it wasn't originally built that way, you have not shared them with us, so if that is the reason you are concerned about safety, you'd have to provide some explanation and preferably also pictures.*

It's not terribly normal, but that may be because it was intended to be wired differently than it is (i.e. the nightlight function mentioned in comments, which you say is not a nightlight.)

An additional possibility without the benefit of pictures to see - there might be a candelabra-base reducing adapter stuck in a regular base socket. I'd be particularly suspecting this if this is "3 lights, spaced 120 degrees apart, all identical otherwise"